# I cannot add C/C++ Nature to Android project in Eclipse

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, opencv, adt

I am writing an Android app which will use OpenCV so I need to use C++ for parts of my app. I am following the tutorials on OpenCV which explain how to include native code in your app. I want to build the native parts using CDT which I have downloaded and installed.

I am following these steps http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_dev_intro.html#cdt-builder

but am stuck at the part that tells me to add C/C++ nature to my project.

I cannot find this option in Eclipse anywhere. It doesn't appear when I right click my project and I have tried adding it from Window >Perspective >customize this perspective >Shortcuts >C/C++ and it isn't there either.

Is there some way that my project could already have C/C++ nature?

I am using Eclipse Juno with ADT.

I'm very new to Android development so I apologise if this is a silly question. Thanks in advance for any help/guidance.

Comment: If you have installed CDT you should have: Window > Open Perspective > Other > (Choose C/C++ from the list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an Android app project, you have an **Android Tools** item in project context menu (i.e. click right mouse on the project name in the left pane).

There you will find **Add Native Support**. It will ask you an *irrelevant* question about the name of the shared library, and it will add an empty C++ file to your `jni` folder. Your project will now have C/C++ nature in addition to its Android/Java nature.